# Java DB Connection Manager Best Practice

Tags: java, sql

I have a connection manager code as follows:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private final String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
    private final String userName = "root";
    private final String userPass = "root";

    private Connection con = null;

    public ConnectionManager() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Connection createConnection() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, userPass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            this.con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

How can I improve this? I am thinking the following improvement:

1. ) create a connection.properties. What is the best way to implement this? Should I put it the call of the property file on a singleton?
2. ) Make the connection singleton.

Thank you.

Comment: `Class.forName(driverName);` need only be ran once. Put it in a `static` initializer block.

Comment: Note that if you call `createConnection()` twice without calling `closeConnection()`, you will have an open `Connection` lying around waiting to get GC'ed. That's no good.

Comment: how can i improve my connection manager above?

Comment: Make it a factory that creates `Connection` objects, but manage those `Connection` objects yourself, outside of this class.

Comment: Do you have sample tutorial website links as to how i can achieve factory that creates connection objects?

Comment: Is this a better implementation? -> https://bitbucket.org/openscg/pgstudio/src/bf806936009b7eeff162baf00d108f5ad60dabd4/src/com/openscg/pgstudio/server/util/ConnectionManager.java

Comment: Is this what you are trying to say about connection factory -> https://svn.codehaus.org/openejb/tags/v0_8beta3/openejb0/src/server/org/openejb/client/ConnectionManager.java

Comment: Something like that, yes. Look into the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface.

Comment: 1) Nowadays, you usually don't need `Class.forName(driverName);` any longer. 2) Consider re-throwing the exceptions (maybe wrapping them in an unchecked exception).

Comment: 3) To make sure, that connections are always closed, you could have a callback interface, where the DB action takes place and afterwards all resources are closed by your class (this has already been invented in Spring e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

If it's for a real application you'd better use a connection pool like this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/.